# HREF target='_blank' does not work in Chrome 79

Tags: browser, href

Using simple HTML code, no JavaScript, nothing fancy, I use this HREF

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Clicking on the link in IE, FireFox, Edge does open a new tab for https://www.example.com on click. In Chrome (version 79), the click just redisplays the current page.

This happens on Chrome desktop and phone (Android). There are no add-ins to my installation of Chrome; no popup or ad blocking installed.

Why doesn't Chrome open a new tab when `target="_blank"` is used? Thanks.

**Added**

The issue seems to be with an HREF being inside a FORM element. The FORM element is as follows:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
```

An HREF with target="_blank" outside the FORM element works properly. Just not inside the FORM element.

But still puzzled as to why that would be the case...and for a workaround or solution.

**Added more - plus code**

There's a button inside the form, and the button contains an image, and the link in the button will not open up a new tab.

Simple form with the button

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <p>inside the form</p> 
 <p><button><a href="https://www.bklnk.com/B004RVZRL0" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150 " width="24" height="24"  class='button_img' alt='delete' /></a> that's a button</button></p>  
 <p><button><a href="https://www.bklnk.com/B004RVZRL0" target="_blank">that's a button</a> </button></p>    
</form>
```

So, with even further testing, the click to open a new tab won't work in Chrome when the HREF is wrapped around an button with an image inside a form. But works in FireFox and Edge.

**Why?**

There are four image/buttons inside the form. The fourth one is the HREF/blank. Items 1-2-3 are form submittals; values need to be passed to the form processing page. The 4th item doesn't need to be processed by the form, but it is inside the form so that all four items will be on the same line. If I place the 4th (HREF/blank) outside of the form, then the 4th item is wrapped around to the next line. 
a

Comment: It works for me. Can you post a [mcve] as I believe there might be more to it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Code sample added. It's an image inside a button inside an HREF inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` tag cannot be opened in a new tab the same way an `<a>` does.

You can use this instead:

```html
<p>
  <button onClick="window.open('https://www.bklnk.com/B004RVZRL0');">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150 " width="24" height="24" class='button_img' alt='delete' />
    that's a button
  </button>
</p>
```

Comment: In my sample code, the IMG tag is surrounded by the HREF. The button surrounds both. So, to my thinking, the button is not processing the HREF link. There are three images that are part of the form which is why an image is inside the button. A fourth image needs to be inside the form (so all images are displayed inline), but needs to do the HREF/blank click. But your code might work for the fourth button, will have to test. Note that only Chrome has the issue. Things work OK in FF and Edge.